# Signal not being triggered on .save method

Tags: django-models, django-signals

I want to create a streaming API(server sent events) for alerts i.e new added alerts should be sent to open connections as server sent events. For that, i am using StreamingHttpResponse. Header is set to text/event-stream as it should be for SSEs. I have a model that handles alerts in DB. I have written a signals.py file that defines signal for post_save for Alert model and for post_save event on Alert model, I return StreamingHttpResponse with newly added alert. When I got the API first time, I get response with all alerts but not getting new added alert/s when ever a new alert is added to DB. What am I doing wrong?

monitoring/signals.py

```
    @receiver(post_save, sender=Alert)
    def send_alert(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        qs_json = serializers.serialize('json', instance)
        return StreamingHttpResponse(qs_json, content_type='text/event-stream')
```

monitoring/views.py

```
    # just importing defined signal receiver here
    from .signals import send_alert
    
    # endpoint view function
    def get_alerts(self):
        queryset = Alert.objects.all().order_by('-date')
        resolved = self.request.query_params.get('resolved')
        server = self.request.query_params.get('server')
        source = self.request.query_params.get('source')
        if source is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(source=source)
        if resolved is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(resolved=resolved)
        if server is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(server=server)
        return HttpResponse(queryset)
```

Even when I hit the .save method on DB myself on Django shell, signal is not triggered.

```
        >>> from monitoring.models import Alert
        >>> a=Alert(container="something")
        >>> s.save()
```

Comment: Signals are not designed to return anything, so the `StreamingHttpResponse` you created there is used by no one. You might have to rethink your design for this.

Comment: @bdbd so how do I make streaming API? given my requirements above

Comment: Besides, my signals are also not being triggered. I added print lines to receiver function and it was not printed on screen showing signal was never triggered.